# Trying to make a windows store app that runs when the laptop lid is closed

Tags: windows-8.1, c#, locking

Is there any way to make an app such that, say the user presses a button (in the app) and directly closes the lid, then the computer doesn't go to sleep (that way my app is still running) and I sort of make my own temporary log in screen as soon as the user opens the lid? (and that login screen essentially freezes all windows 8 functionality until the user logs in)

Im trying to make an alarm app that can only be shut off by logging in.

Also the app in question is a windows store app (written in C#) for windows 8.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, with administrative privileges.  Lid signal handling is part of the OS power settings and is controllable from an app if it is run as administrator or obtains admin privileges at runtime with UAC.

Powercfg can do this if you run a sub-process with cmd /c:

```
powercfg -setacvalueindex 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 0
powercfg -setdcvalueindex 5ca83367-6e45-459f-a27b-476b1d01c936 0
```

There may be a .NET API for power management as well.

Comment: Could you explain it to me a little bit more?As Im a beginner and I have just finished learning C#

Comment: Thank you I'll check them out.